# Manage MP3 ID3 tags server-side

Tags: storage, audio, mp3

I'm looking for a script / software to edit and keep track of a remote mp3 storage. Especially I want to edit ID3-Tags.. Any ideas? Does such a manager software exist?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found **getID3()**: http://getid3.sourceforge.net/ (bad usability, but does it's job). This is almost exactly what I was looking for. Sorry, I didn't write that I'm looking for a web-based interface. *id3v2* is also great though, but not suitable for non pros :)

Thanks, though!

Answer (score 1):

the `id3v2` program is a powerful command-line tool to edit id3 tags. MusicBrainz `picard` is a GUI tool that can also lookup a central mp3 signature repository.

Comment: sorry, I was looking for something with a web-based interface... thanks, though!